# Python ijson on badly organized json

Tags: python, json, ijson

I'm trying to get data out of Kontakt.io's MQTT broker. This is the format it's providing, including the leading b' and trailing '

```
    b'[
        {
            "timestamp":1530121741,
            "sourceId":"OaBW9",
            "trackingId":"t7J5",
            "rssi":-57,
            "proximity":"IMMEDIATE",
            "scanType":"BLE",
            "deviceAddress":"ea:21:88:b3:d2:5f"
        },
        {
            "timestamp":1530121741,
            "sourceId":"OaBW9",
            "trackingId":"t7J5",
            "rssi":-68,
            "proximity":"IMMEDIATE",
            "scanType":"BLE",
            "deviceAddress":"ea:21:88:b3:d2:5f"
        }
    ]'
```

Seeing as there's no organization in the JSON other than in blocks, how can I actually pull the data from it using keys?

I've tried:

```
    test = ijson.items(str(msg.payload), 'rssi.item')
    columns = list(test)
    print(columns[0])
```

As seen in many examples, but I can't figure out how to make it work without "burrowing" into JSON trees (as in the earth.europe.etc.item examples seen everywhere). Should I be trying to get rssi.item using array indexes or something like that? Should I trim the json's " b' " and trailing " ' "?

I don't work with Python very often, so I feel a little out in the water with this.

Comment: That is a `bytes` literal (think of it as a more primitive `str` type for now, Python `str` types are actually unicode sequences). You need to deserialize this `bytes` object into a python object, and work with that. Use the `json` module.

Comment: @EmilePels yes, and that is incorrect. You need to use `msg.payload.decode()` or else it returns a string version of the *string representation* of the bytes literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with help by Konstantin and juanpa.arrivillaga's answers combined. 
Used **import json** *not* **ijson**

```
    test = json.loads(msg.payload.decode())
    print([x.get('rssi') for x in test])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
import json 

a = b'''[
        {
            "timestamp":1530121741,
            "sourceId":"OaBW9",
            "trackingId":"t7J5",
            "rssi":-57,
            "proximity":"IMMEDIATE",
            "scanType":"BLE",
            "deviceAddress":"ea:21:88:b3:d2:5f"
        },
        {
            "timestamp":1530121741,
            "sourceId":"OaBW9",
            "trackingId":"t7J5",
            "rssi":-68,
            "proximity":"IMMEDIATE",
            "scanType":"BLE",
            "deviceAddress":"ea:21:88:b3:d2:5f"
        }
    ]'''


b = json.loads(a)
print([x.get('rssi') for x in b])
```

Output:

```
[-57, -68]
```

Comment: what is the difference between passing msg.payload, and surrounding it with 3 single quotes? I'm getting an error when I try using this method and setting b = json.loads(msg.payload) but I get an error

Comment: @T1960CT almost certainly, Konstantin is using Python 2 (or else this would throw an error) and you are using Python 3, where `bytes` and `str` are simply aliases to the same type.